# Writing an application to compare the shapes of images (ex: what state does this potato chip look most like?) and would like some help getting started

Tags: image, comparison, edge-detection, states

I am looking to build an application for my boyfriend's birthday gift and would like some help getting started!

I'd like to be able to input a photo (of a potato chip or something with distinct edges) and have the app select & output which state in the US the chip looks most like. I plan on building this in Java and am wondering what the best approach to designing the algorithm would be. I've never done anything with edge detection or image comparisons and am wondering if you anyone could point me in the right direction in terms of getting started.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look into Caffe, implemented by Berkeley. It uses neural networks to identify objects based of learning from models.

For your specific task, you can create models of different potato chips and Caffe will "learn" them. Then, you can write an application using a video camera where you can place a potato chip in the video feed and Caffe will identify it.

For any identification process, you need both feature detection but also object matching to a database of similar images, and Caffe can help with that.